# Android Disable back button

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I want to disable back button in my application. And if not possible, then I want to open MainActivity when click on it. Is there any solution? If yes help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code for onback button click to intent another activity.

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Caly_act.this,MainActivity_tab.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks this one is working.

Comment: welcome make +1@dineshsheoran

Comment: what is wrong in my code why someone make downvoted it?

Comment: working for me i dont know for others.

Answer (score 2):

simply write these lines

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

Comment: this is not working

Comment: show me your code. how's this possible. is it Activity class?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use this if you want to disable completely back button:

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(false);
    }
```

Comment: Can we disable or change action for home button

Comment: The above code is for the back button.

Comment: i know but now i am asking for HOME button